# d3 rect interpolation

Tags: d3.js

I have a data set of forecasted margins for a large number of industries, i.e. 
for each industry I have a probability distribution of the form

```
 var data = [{'confidence': 0.0, 'rule': 'Agriculture', 'value': 45},
 {'confidence': 0.052631578947368418, 'rule': 'Agriculture', 'value': 46},
 {'confidence': 0.10526315789473684, 'rule': 'Agriculture', 'value': 47},
 {'confidence': 0.15789473684210525, 'rule': 'Agriculture', 'value': 48},
 {'confidence': 0.36842105263157893, 'rule': 'Agriculture', 'value': 52},
 {'confidence': 0.73684210526315785, 'rule': 'Information', 'value': 59},
 {'confidence': 0.78947368421052633, 'rule': 'Machine Learning', 'value': 60},
 {'confidence': 0.84210526315789469, 'rule': 'Machine Learning', 'value': 61},
 {'confidence': 0.89473684210526305, 'rule': 'Machine Learning', 'value': 62},
 {'confidence': 0.94736842105263153, 'rule': 'Machine Learning', 'value': 63}];
```

I need to recreate the  following plot in d3.js, in which each density is plotted as
as a bar chart where the linear color scale describes the probabilities.

[image: Example visualization]

My attempt so far has consisted of plotting each given point as a rect element of height 1:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
              .data(data)
              .enter()
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                  return x(d.rule) + margin.left;
              })
              .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                  return y(d.value) 
              })
              .attr("width", 100)
              .attr("height", 1) // change this !
              .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                  return color(d.confidence);
              });
```

As you can see below this sort of works, but I now need to somehow interpolate the rects 
to get a more smooth visualization.

[image: unsmoothed]

How can I achieve this (or am I on the wrong path altogether) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing what you want is to use [SVG gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp). For each bar, you would define a gradient with stops corresponding to your confidence values (generated much the same way that you're generating the rects now). Then all you have to do is draw the rects and assign the gradients as fill to the respective ones.

I have used this techniques to fill the "lines" [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/).